# Is there any way to make my android application smaller?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm creating a new application for Android. It's my first application. It works with instrumental songs, but every song that I put there, is 3mb. My app is a group of 6 instrumental songs.

Is there any way to make my app smaller?

Comment: Don't include the songs in the app, download them from a server when the app is installed: offer the user a choice of where to put them (implying that they should put the songs on an external storage device).

Comment: what do you mean by "put there"  do you have to have the songs as part of the program, or can you stream them?  if you stream the songs that would be the best way to do it I think

Comment: i guess that streaming probably wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: I mean download them into somewhere where they can be accessed: I did not mean streaming.  Upon further consideration, if your content is static then expansion files (mentioned by Waza) would also be a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

Use Play Store expansion files.

Google Play hosts and serves the expansion files at no charge

The files can be any file type you want and are saved to the device's shared storage

> User selects to install your app from Google Play.
>
> If Google Play is able to download the expansion files (which is the case for most
>   devices), it downloads them along with the APK. If Google Play is
>   unable to download the expansion files, it downloads the APK only.
>
> When the user launches your application, your app must check whether
>   the expansion files are already saved on the device.
>
> If yes, your app
>   is ready to go. If no, your app must download the expansion files over
>   HTTP from Google Play. Your app must send a request to the Google Play
>   client using the Google Play's Application Licensing service, which
>   responds with the name, file size, and URL for each expansion file.
>
> With this information, you then download the files and save them to
>   the proper storage location.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

> Each time you upload an APK using the Google Play Developer Console,
>   you have the option to add one or two expansion files to the APK. Each
>   file can be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose, but we
>   recommend you use a compressed file to conserve bandwidth during the
>   download. Conceptually, each expansion file plays a different role.

Answer (score 3):

Download these songs at first launch from your server into sdcard.